# How to execute stored procedure with object table data parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, proc

I have been trying to call a stored procedure (from Pro*C code) and trying to get the output which is a table of complex type but keep running into brick walls. After a long and thorough search on the Internet I could not find a solution how to get data from parameter in Pro*C code. I wonder if it is possible at all.

I have a stored procedure that has an OUT parameter of TABLE type holding complex type.

Here's the code that I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OT_POOL_DATA_SRC_DATA AS OBJECT
(
  src        VARCHAR2(40),
  start_date DATE,
  end_date   DATE,
  data       NUMBER
)

TYPE Sources_period_data IS TABLE OF OT_POOL_DATA_SRC_DATA INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE Get_slaves_period_data(label  IN VARCHAR2,
                                   period_data OUT Sources_period_data);
```

I'll be glad if someone tell me how this can happen.

Comment: Maybe you can include your current Pro\*C code for the call? There is a section on [collections in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_18col.htm); have you got anywhere from the nested table examples?

Comment: The signature and the name of the procedure look rather odd to me.  Just going by the name of the procedure and the signature, this is screaming out that it should be a pipelined table function not a procedure with an OUT parameter.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Thank you for your comment!Using pipelined table function solve my problem!